# number of parameters is always returning 0 in bash

Tags: bash

```
echo number of params is... "$#"
#checks to see if the correct amount of params are passed in
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ];then
    echo "ERROR: please pass in a ip address"
    exit 1
fi
```

I enter the command "./RJ_APM.sh 1 2 3" and the output is...

```
[User ~/Desktop/Task_Automation/mini_Proj_1]$ ./RJ_APM.sh 1 2 3 
number of params is... 0
ERROR: please pass in a ip address
```

Comment: If it is a Bash script, insert `#! /bin/bash` in the first line of the script.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the code shown; I see `$#` expanding to 3, not 0.

Answer (score -1):

It works for me.. Check if the SHELL variable is pointing to bash

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: if [ $# -ne 1 ];then

Comment: `$#` is not `bash`-specific, and the value of `$SHELL` is only tenuously related to the shell used to execute the script in the first place.